# What to put for website when registering android app with instagram api?

Tags: android, api, instagram

I am new to Android and am confused on what to put for the URL fields when registering a new client with the Instagram API using their web form.

I'm specifically confused as to what to put for these fields:

Website URL

Valid Redirect URIs

I am making an Android app and it doesn't have a website, so what am I supposed to be putting here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an Instagram Access Token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496511/how-to-get-an-instagram-access-token)

Comment: @F.Klein no it's not since i have not even registered my client since I'm not sure how to fill in the fields for the form to even register the app. I'm not sure what is meant by website URL and redirect URIs. I want to register my android app with the instagram API, but the android app itself doesn't have a corresponding site, so i'm confused as to what i need to put for the website field and redirect field.

Comment: Then it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732454/how-to-register-new-client-on-instagram-api especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/21930848/1661938 covers your problem.

Comment: @F.Klein I did read that post and answer before, but I still don't understand what the responder meant. Also, I feel that it isn't the best practice to put a throw away URL to gain the access token. It seems like a poor work around imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my search for an answer that made sense to me, I found this: http://oferei.com/2013/06/serverless-instagram-authentication/

In short, this is what one would need to know about how to fill these fields if they are registering an app that does not have its own website:

Website URL: it doesn't matter what value goes here, I used **localhost**

Redirect URIs: The article above specifies a custom URI scheme, but this is not supported w/ the Instagram API anymore. However, I did see that also using **localhost** would work here as well in this article: http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token

Not sure if that is the best practice, but it is a way to get the client ID for an Android app.