# Instagram API: How to obtain an access token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need to make a PHP application that, given a hashtag, returns to me a XML with the posts related to that hashtag.

I logged into Instagram in the Developers section and filled the application setup form.

A "Client ID" and "Client Secret" were generated, but I did not see a generated Token Access anywhere.

One of the fields asks for "Valid redirect URIs:" but the application has not started being done yet, it will be all developed localhost and only then will it be published in a hosting provider.

In this case, how can I develop my functionality? What do I need to do to gain access granted by Instagram?

I found an online tool through which you type Client ID and Client Secret and it returns the Access Token.

However, the result was: {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

Comment: I forgot to mention that I found an online tool through which you type Client ID and Client Secret and it returns the Access Token. However, the result was:
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register new client on Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732454/how-to-register-new-client-on-instagram-api)

Answer (score 2):

Recently(last week) Instagram has stopped accepting submissions of new apps, That is the reason you are facing this problem to create new access token.
https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

Although for the already registered app, you can still get more access token by adding the additional new users.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/03/26/facebook-platform-changes/

**Pause app review: We paused app review last week while we implement new changes to our platform.**

---

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication

> ## Receiving an access_token
>
> In order to receive an `access_token`, you must do the following:
>
> 1. Direct the user to our authorization url.
>
>    - If the user is not logged in, they will be asked to log in.
>    - The user will be asked if they would like to grant your application access to her Instagram data.
> 2. The server will redirect the user in one of two ways that you
>      choose:
>
>    - **Server-side flow (recommended):** Redirect the user to a URI of your    choice. Take the provided **code** parameter and exchange it
>        for an    access_token by POSTing the code to our `access_token` url.
>    - **Implicit flow:** Instead of handling a code, we include the    `access_token` as a fragment (#) in the URL. This method is less secure, but allows applications without any server component to receive an `access_token`.

Hope this will be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. Tried a few things, but doing this was the easiest:

http://instagram.pixelunion.net

As soon as I got my access token and user id, I made sure to revoke access literally the next minute. Hope it helps!

Comment: this service is now deactivated